# Short story about people who believe that they are travelling to another world\dimension, but are really in another country

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can anyone identify a short science fiction story, probably from the 1960s-1980s about a group of Victorian era-styled explorers who travel through a portal and end up in a strange and fantastical land surrounded by strange plants and animals.

They believe that they are in another dimension or on another planet, have some grand adventures before returning home as heroes who united the two people on either side of the portal.

The epilogue is that one day far in the future another explorer is travelling by airship (which is a new invention at the time) to the edge of the known world, and he stumbles on another continent that turns out to be the land on the other side of the portal.

The twist is that they're simply living on different hemispheres of the same planet.